# Stop Google showing a cached copy of my website

Tags: google-search

Can I give some directives to let Google scan my site but not allow users to see the cached version when they click on the "cache" link on the Google search page?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put this Meta tag on pages you don't want the 'Cached' link to show for:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noarchive">
```

From Google's [Meta Tags](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=en) documentation:

> `noarchive`: prevents Google from showing the Cached link for a page.

Comment: More detail here: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156412

Comment: after that will my page be shown in search result on same position (how will it influence on google SERP).

Comment: @Constantine: I believe it shouldn't have any influence. But you will have to wait until the next crawling for google to see and follow the "don't cache" instruction.

Comment: This is only a partial answer: it only works for HTML pages. To make it work on all types of documents, use the X-Robots-Tag: HTTP response header instead.

Comment: ... which is also partial: not all crawlers support it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta name="robots" content="noarchive">
```

Read this for details:
http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=156412

Answer (score 0):

[Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/robots_meta_tag?hl=en) provides two options for telling Google not to offer cached copies of pages:

1. Add a meta tag to your HTML pages (as the other answers say). Drawbacks:

   1. Injecting that meta tag into all of your HTML may not be easy.
   2. This only affects HTML documents, not other types of documents (images, PDF, etc.) - but I don't know whether Google offers cached copies of non-HTML documents in the first place.
2. Set the following HTTP Response header on all of your documents:

   ```
   X-Robots-Tag: noarchive,nosnippet
   ```

By the way, [Bing supports the first method](https://www.bing.com/webmasters/help/which-robots-metatags-does-bing-support-5198d240); [apparently, it doesn't support the second one](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/forum/all/bing-ignores-header-set-x-robots-tag-directives/d8282218-b3ff-48a6-a112-508de2e24f62?auth=1).